# How to set map value to attribute in aura component

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning, aura

I have an apex method which is returning map in the form of Map<string,Object> and map will contains only one record

Can anyone help me how can I set attribute on component from map value

On component, I have two string attributes string1 and string2

From Java script, I want to set

```
component.set('v.string1',map.field1)
component.set('v.string2',map.field2)

doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
    //sai start
    var action = component.get('c.showSearch');
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
    var state = response.getState();
    if(state === 'SUCCESS') {
        var result = response.getReturnValue();
            component.set('v.searchHub', response.getReturnValue().Search_Hub_Name__c);
            component.set('v.name2',response.getReturnValue().Visualforce_Component_Name__c);
    } else {
        console.log('Error: ' + response.getError());
    }
    });
```

Can anyone help on this please

Comment: Harish, can you share the map and it's values

Comment: Mukul, map values in debug is 
{Access_Permission=Search__mdt:{Permission_Set_Name__c=Access_Permission, Hub_Name__c=ArticlesPanel, Visualforce_Name__c=article-hub}}

Comment: I simply want to put map.field1 to attribute1 and map.field2 to attribute2

Comment: Log the map in the browser's  console so I can understand how the map is formed.

Comment: I have added apex class code in question which is creating map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why return a map if you only need to return one object?

Assuming there's a good reason for returning a map:

An Apex Map should become a standard Javascript object when it arrives at the front end.

To access it, if you know the name, you can get the object out of the map like this:

```
let accessPermissionObj = yourResultObject['Access_Permission'];
```

Now you have the object, you can access the fields as you were before:

```
component.set('v.string1',accessPermissionObj.Hub_Name__c)
component.set('v.string2',accessPermissionObj.Visualforce_Name__c)
```

If you don't know the key of the map, you can iterate like so:

```
Object.keys(yourResultObject).forEach(obj => {
  //do something with your object
  component.set('v.string1',obj.Hub_Name__c);
  //you'd normally put this object in an array or apply a map function
})
```

---

**If** you wanted to return just one object, your Apex method would look like:

public static Coveo_Similar_Search__mdt showSearch(){}

this would be the result of your Aura server call.
And you'd just use the result directly:

```
var result = response.getReturnValue();

component.set('v.string1', result.Hub_Name__c)
component.set('v.string2', result.Visualforce_Name__c)
```

Comment: thanks for helping out here, if I return object instead of map then how can I assign object field to attributes

Comment: updated with an example of this.

Comment: Thanks a ton Caspar Harmer for helping here

Comment: how can I define result object here, I added aura server call code in question

Comment: updated question

Comment: how can I define result object here